# Java, Threads, will only run() block be part of the thread or also the code after a start() call?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm starting Threads in java, I would like to have a clear idea of how `start()`/`run()` acts in my situation.

I've created a thread calle t, and I've placed `t.start()` followed by a for cycle.

Will the for cycle be part of the thread.t or is it part of the main thread??

---

```
class Job implements Runnable{
Thread t;

    Job(String tName){
        t=new Thread(this, tName);
        System.out.println("This is thread: "+t.getName());
        t.start();
        System.out.println("This is the end of constructor");
        try{   /*<<<<<<<------------WILL THIS RUN in my MAIN thread or in the t thread??*/
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println("xxxThis is the count i value: "+i+" "+ t.getName());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("The thread has been interrupted");
        }

    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("This is the start of RUN()");
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println("This is the count i value: "+i+" "+ t.getName());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("The thread has been interrupted");
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Fnally block reached: "+t.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI don't use `new Thread`, learn to use [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have a clear idea of how start()/run() acts in my situation

`start()` method spawns a new thread of execution and executes the run method in that thread. In this case , the thread will have its own `call stack`. Whereas, calling `run()` method directly doesn't spawns a new thread. Instead this will cause the `run()` method to execute in the current executing thread having old call stack.

> Will the for cycle be part of the thread.t or is it part of the main thread??

The `for` cycle will be part of the `Thread`(in your case is `main` thread if you create `Job` instance in main thread) from which Thread `t` is spawned. And if you want to confirm then simply print the name of `thread` which is executing that for loop using `Thread.currentThread().getName()` . Example:

```
try{   /*<<<<<<<------------WILL THIS RUN in my MAIN thread or in the t thread??*/
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is executing this for loop");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("xxxThis is the count i value: "+i+" "+ t.getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a simple but good hint. Thanks to all the other people for the prompt responses, they cleared me lots of other doubts.

Comment: Notice my comment about starting a thread in an object constructor @Luther.

Answer (score 2):

The method `t.start()` and the following `try/for` code are executed in the same thread. This is the main thread if you called the Job(String) constructor from the main thread.

The `run()` method is executed in the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the for cycle be part of the `thread.t` or is it part of the main thread??

The main thread.  When a thread is forked, the new `Thread` just calls the `run()` method.   In your case, the main thread calls `start()` and then continues to run the `for()` method.  This actually will most likely be called *before* the new thread is finished starting.  The new thread that is forked only calls the `run()` method and any other methods used by `run()`.

FYI, it is considered very bad practice to start a thread from within an object constructor.  This "leaks" references to the current object while it is still being initialized.  You should consider adding a `start()` method onto the `Job` or call `start()` after the `Job` constructor has finished.

```
 Job job = new Job(...);
 job.start();
```

Also, since the main thread is the one running your `for` loop, it will throw `InterruptedException` only if the main thread gets interrupted -- not the `Job` thread.

```
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("The thread has been interrupted");
    }
```