# why does the user-written run method() start a new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that you start a thread by either implementing the `Runnable` interface, or extending the `Thread` class. To implement the `Runnable` interface, I am told that I simply create a class with a `run()` method, in which I can put whatever code I want to run in the thread.

My confusion is this:

The `run()` method's body is nothing but application code specific to the user. So how does Java actually start a thread? In other words, where is the code that actually initiates a thread? I haven't seen the `Runnable` interface (don't know where to find it), but since it is just an interface, all it can have is static variables and method signatures. Isn't that so?

Comment: You pass a `Runnable` *to* a `Thread`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, Threads, will only run() block be part of the thread or also the code after a start() call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285284/java-threads-will-only-run-block-be-part-of-the-thread-or-also-the-code-afte)

Comment: Note that `Runnable` really doesn't inherently have anything to do with threads, although the main reason for providing this class was for threads.  But you can use it for anything where you want an object that has a `run()` method.  I've used it for cases where I want to queue actions to be performed later, without creating a new thread to perform them.

Comment: Thread support, (eg. creation), in all sane implementations, would be provided by the underlying OS.  The OS manages I/O, so it must manage the threads of execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [javadoc of Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

> When an object implementing interface Runnable is used to create a
>   thread, starting the thread causes the object's run method to be
>   called in that separately executing thread.

Java creates a new thread, and that thread executes the code that you put into your `run()` method when you start it.

You need to pass the runnable as a parameter to the Thread's constructor:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ObjectThatImplementsRunnable());
t.start();
```

From the javadoc of [Thread.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can find information in the [Thread javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). It describes both way of running threads. The `Runnable` part tells:

> The other way to create a thread is to declare a class that implements the Runnable interface. That class then implements the run method. An instance of the class can then be allocated, passed as an argument when creating Thread, and started. The same example in this other style looks like the following:
>
> ```
> class PrimeRun implements Runnable {
>     long minPrime;
>     PrimeRun(long minPrime) {
>         this.minPrime = minPrime;
>     }
>
>     public void run() {
>         // compute primes larger than minPrime
>         . . .
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The following code would then create a thread and start it running:
>
> ```
> PrimeRun p = new PrimeRun(143);
> new Thread(p).start();
> ```